# Why can't I replace a newline in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below illustrates the trouble I am having reading from an Excel file and removing unnecessary newline characters.  How can I remove the newline character in the second book's title?

**Data from Books.xlsx**

```
BookID,Title,Author
1,"I, Robot",Rob
2,Robots
and me,Rob
3,I made a robot,Rob
4,Robotics for dummies,Rob
```

```
# pandas version is 1.2.0
import pandas

def fromxl():
    master_tracker = "data_in\\books.xlsx"
    
    df = pandas.read_excel(master_tracker, "Sheet1", header=0)

    # doesn't work
    # df.replace('\n', ' ')

    # doesn't work
    # for r in df.iterrows():
    #     r[1][1] = r[1][1].replace('\n', ' ')

    print(df)
```

*Edit*
Just for clarification, here is what I get when I print the dataframe

```
   BookID                 Title Author
0       1              I, Robot    Rob
1       2        Robots\nand me    Rob
2       3        I made a robot    Rob
3       4  Robotics for dummies    Rob
```

Comment: So, you just want to remove '\n'?

Comment: Ain't there too many arrays in `r[1][1] = r[1][1].replace('\n', ' ')`? `r[1]` is the cell and `r[1][1]` is the second character of the text in that cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
`df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace("\n"," ")`

This will replace every line breaker, with a simple space, in every row.

If you want for all columns:
`df = df.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)`

Comment: This worked!  Is there a way to do this against all columns in case newlines appear in those, too?

Comment: df = df.str.replace("\n", " ") For all columns.

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Try without '.str'.

Comment: Removing `.str` did not work.  It didn't throw an error, either.  Just didn't remove the newline.

Comment: df = df.replace(['\n'], ' ')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227150/discussion-between-robert-simpson-and-l-papadopoulos).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for multiple columns:

```
for i in df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns:    
    df[i]=df[i].str.replace("/n",'')
```

Comment: throws error: 'Can only use .str accessor with string values!'

Comment: that works, but @L. Papadopoulos discovered a one-liner that worked, too.  it was `df = df.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)`   Purely for academic purposes, it might be worthwhile to benchmark both solutions to know which is faster.

Comment: the test resulted in the DataFrame.replace method being marginally faster.  Really not much faster, so either approach seems reasonable unless there's a need to squeeze tenths of a second from your application.